# creating and verifying a pointer into "if" statement

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

Is this code correct?

```
void foo ( int* p )
{
  if ( int* p2 = p ) // single "="
  {
    *p2++;
  }
}
```

I always been thinking it's not, but recently i've saw such code in a colleague's of mine sources.

What if "p" is NULL? MS VS 2008 works correct but shows "warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression".

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, in a sufficient new version of the C++ standard (C++03 or C++11)

Comment: I think its warning you simply that your defintion pointer to an int will go out of scope if it fails the conditional. So as long as it doesn't fail the condition you can perform you assignmnet within the if statement, but not within an else statement or outside the if statement.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Or C++98.  It wasn't legal in the ARM, but it has been legal in all ISO standard C++.

Comment: `if (mind m = blown) ++vote; // +1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By raising [warning C4706](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hw7c1he%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the compiler is simply questioning whether you actually meant to write `if ( int* p2 == p )` instead of `if ( int* p2 = p )` as shown.

Per 6.4 of the 2003 C++ Standard, `if ( int* p2 = p )` is legal:

> The value of a *condition* [`if (condition)`] that is an initialized
>   declaration in a statement other than a `switch` statement is the
>   value of the declared variable implicitly converted to type `bool`.

If `p` is `NULL`, *condition* (`int* p2 = p`) fails because the value of `p2` is 0, and thus implicitly `false`, and `*p2` is *not* incremented.

Comment: soooo... this post is upvoted and accpted, despite being wrong (`if ( int* p2 == p )` isn't legal _and_ not helpful if it were). Someone help me out with this?!

Comment: Warning C4706 is flagging `if ( int* p2 = p )` as a possible spot where you actually meant to use `==` (even if the expression would be wrong -- go figure).

Comment: @sehe  It's perfectly legal. Check out 6.4 *"The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a switch statement is the
value of the declared variable contextually converted to bool"*

Comment: @Pubby: Ok, I scanned it; nowhere can I find that you can declare a new variable inside the condition, while _not initializing_ but still comparing the (undefined) value to another in the condition expression.... Did you (a) try to compile it (b) see the `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: @sehe Oh whoops, I didn't notice the `==`.

Comment: @Pubby: cheers. I can't believe how far _off_ the answers and voting are on this question. There must be something in the water today :) My answer has acquired 2 downvotes - eek! _people are blind_ :)

Comment: There is no `==` in the OP's question. The **compiler warning C4706** is asking: "Instead of `if ( int* p2 = p )`, did you actually mean to write `if ( int* p2 == p )`?" Per 6.4 of the Standard -- yes, the code in the OP's question is correct.

Comment: @sehe: Please look carefully, there is "if ( int* p2 = p )" in OP's code. Gnawme explained the meaning of the warning quite good.

Comment: @fogbit The compiler warning speaks about "assignment" and a "conditional expression".  There is neither an assignment nor a conditional expression in the original code.  The only possible explination of the meaning of the warning is that it is meaningless, because it doesn't apply to the code in question.  The answer here is simply wrong.

Comment: @sehe Re the voting: it happens all the time.  Votes here are largely meaningless, since wrong postings do get accepted and up voted.

Comment: @JamesKanze: not in my experience: wrong answers always get 'appreciated' to their value, this is a very very rare occurrence in my experience (at least on the tags in which I'm active). Now, with the 'softer' questions ("how can I improve this algorithm") I agree, sometimes rather low-quality answers get written / accepted (I admit to having written some of those answers myself in the past)

Comment: @Gnawme: I just noticed you put a new comment, sry for missing it earlier. I think it is interesting that you finally write the answer in a comment :) Anyways, cheers

Comment: @sehe It varies.  With regards to acceptance, the system might be improved by not allowing an answer to be accepted until a certain time after the question was posted; all too often, the poster doesn't know enough C++ to distinguish between "correct" and "seems to work in my environment", and accepts the first answer which seems to work (presumably to regret it when later answers point out the flaws in the accepted answer).  As for votes, if there are a lot, maybe, but when there aren't many voters, the results seem fairly random to me.

Comment: @sehe: If I had realized that the answer was not as obvious as I first thought, I would have expanded my answer. But then it would have looked like your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The warning *`assignment within conditional expression`* is usually issued by compilers to prevent cases where you write

```
 if (a = b) 
 {
```

where you **meant**

```
 if (a == b) // big difference!
 {
```

In your sample, the **'assignment warning' is actually bogus**, since it is, in fact, not an assignment, but rather an intialization:

```
 {
      int *p2 = p;
      if (p2)
      {

      }
 }
```

and there is *no risk* that you'd actually wanted the syntax error (`int *p2 == p` ?!) instead :)

The rest of your post is perfectly valid C++03 (and later) and just does what it says<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> 
(which in terms of lasting effect, isn't much because

- p2 is dereferenced without ever *doing* something with it
- p2 is incremented without ever *doing* something with it,

but I guess that's just the sample code? In case it isn't obvious, `*p2++` is equivalent to `*p2; p2++;`)

Comment: That's the way voting works here.  It's more or less random, or a popularity contest, wrong answers are often voted up and accepted, and correct answers voted down.  Your answer is correct; about the only possible criticism I can think of is that you didn't also say that there was no "conditional expression" either.  (Not that that's important---the absence of assignment is the critical issue, showing that whoever put that message in the compiler didn't understand C++.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: nicely put, I'm happy enough now; things have balanced out a bit better in the long run

Answer (score 4):

It's formally correct (in C++, but not in C).  Allowing a definition as
a conditional was added with `dynamic_cast`, to support such things as:

```
if ( Derived* p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>( ptrToBase ) ) {
    //  ...
}
```

The argument was that there would never be a moment where `p` was in
scope, but not null.  After the `if`, `p` is no longer in scope.

The argument doesn't hold water, since on one hand, if you add an
`else`, within the `else` block, `p` is in scope, and null.  And the
justification involving limiting the scope really isn't very strong
anyway, because if the function is long enough for it to matter, the
function is too long and too complex.  This construct supports things
like:

```
if ( Derived1* p = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>( ptrToBase ) ) {
    // ...
}
if ( Derived2* p = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>( ptrToBase ) ) {
    // ...
}
// ...
```

But this really isn't something you want to do in good code.

All in all, I'd avoid the construct, replacing it with something like:

```
int* p2 = p;
if ( p2 != NULL ) {
    //  ...
}
```

It's more explicit and more readable.  It does mean that `p2` is in
scope outside the `if`, but I'd argue that if this causes any problems,
the function itself needs refactoring, because it is too long and too
complex.

EDIT:

With regards to the warning: it's a complete idiocy on the part of the
compiler.  There's no assignment within the conditional expression:
there's no assignment, period, and there's no “conditional
expression” the condition in the original is a declaration, not an
expression.
**If** the compiler wanted to warn about something (on stylistic
grounds, because it agrees with me that this is bad style), then it
should warn about an implicit conversion to `bool`.  (And of course,
whether this warning is emitted should be under control of an option.
The compiler should compile the language, not impose style, unless one
asks it explicitly to warn about specific style issues.)

Comment: Could you eplain why there is no assigments? Isn't 'if( **int* p2 = p** )' an assignment?

Comment: @fogbit No.  It's a declaration.  The `=` sign is pure syntax here, not an operator.

Answer (score 2):

the code is error prone (why not break it into 2 statements) but otherwise correct.
 if you break this into:

```
void foo ( int* p )
{
  int* p2 = p;
  if ( p2 ) 
  {
    *p2++;
  }
}
```

it is more readable and won't give you the warning. You can see it's also correct (in case of null you are just assigning p2 with null, which is ok).

Comment: I agree that you should rewrite it as above, but the point of doing so is to be able to make the `if` explicit: `if ( p != NULL )`, and avoid the confusing implicit conversion pointer to bool.

Comment: I wouldn't rewrite it as above, I'd rewrite it `if (p) { int *p2 = p; ... }`. Optionally `if (p != 0)` or `if (p != NULL)` instead of `if (p)`. Or actually I'd rewrite it `return;`, since the questioner's function does nothing...

Answer (score 1):

If p is NULL, the condition fails. So the code is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems odd. It's correct, but I fail to see in which cases is it useful.
It's less readable then simple alternatives (like Oren S. mentioned), and needlessly defines a new variable in order to increment (*p). The parameter p is already a new variable on the stack, why create another one?

Comment: The code creates a pointer within if-statement and deletes it at the statement end. Using Oren's variant forces a programmer to write addiditional "{}" in this case, which makes the coe less readble IMHO.

Comment: @fogbit How does Oren's variant for an additional "{}"?

Comment: @JamesKanze: **{** int* p2 = p; if (p2) *p2++; **}**. One has to  embrace the code in "{}" if he doesn't want "p2" to exist after "*p2++" operation.

Comment: @fogbit it's true that p2 will exist after the if in Oren S.'s variant, but what you say enhances my point. Why define p2 in the first place?

Comment: @fogbit And why wouldn't one "want" p2 after the operation?  What problem does it cause?  Who cares if it's in scope or not?

Comment: @JamesKanze: what if you have a smart/COM pointer? Isn't it good to do release right after you don't need an pointer?

Comment: @fogbit That's why you return from the function.  If you absolutely need the release earlier, for reasons of program logic, then you should make it explicit, and call release.  For the most part, however, if you're using smart pointers, it's because you don't care about the actual moment of release, as long as someone does it.

Comment: why do you write `(for int i = 0 ; ....)` instead of `{ int i = 0; for (; i < ...) }` then? Why do we use RAII? I prefer release something i don't need with "{}" instead of explicit release.

Answer (score 0):

Look at int* p  as this "p is a pointer to an int". And, "p2 is also a pointer to an int". You are making p2 point to the pointer that p is also pointing to when you say p2 = p. The statement *p2++; will increment the address by 4 and point to something besides the int you were originally pointing to.  Whichi should be a 32bit integer. The pointer increments by 4 on a 32bit compiler.   If you use (*p2)++ wrapped in parenthesis it will increment the integer the pointer is pointing to.

Yes it works... wierd.

```
int ClassPtr::MethodA(int *p)
{
    if (int *p2 = p)
    {
       (*p2)++;
       return *p2;
    }
          return 0; 
}
```

Comment: BTW 0 Errors and 0 Warnings! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think grammatically the code has no problem. But it is not a good style.
If you definitely know there is single "=", you can also wite like this:

```
if ((int* p2 = p) != NULL)
{
    *p2++;
}
```

I prefer the pointer compares to NULL.

Comment: No you can't.  Your version is not legal C++; you can't put a declaration in parentheses, as part of a larger expression.

Comment: This doesn't compile at all!